# Showing specific div when clicked on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Me and my friend are building a website to show menus of certain restaurants around our campus. We're trying to make a one page website. There are two main divs on the page. One of them show the restaurants list and the other one is supposed to show the menu of the selected restaurant from the restaurants list.

There are too many questions about this on the web and we've tried countless of fiddles but we couldn't manage to get them working. Last 2 fiddles we've tried are the following:

```
> https://jsfiddle.net/VpkKn/387/

> https://jsfiddle.net/n53qg/
```

Our page is: http://178.62.254.14/test/

Can you guide us how to correctly use these fiddles? We've imported the jquery library and tried to put these scripts on different positions on the page including the head tag of the page.

Edit: Code of the page may look a little bit messy because we're also learning the html at the same time. We're sorry for that :)

Summary for the code of the page is as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"      
type="text/css">
<link href="css/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script    
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
<title>Kalkanlı Keyif</title>
</head>

<body>

<header>
    <div class="w3-container">
        <div id="logocontainer" class="w3-col" style="width: 20%">
            <img src="images/logo.png"> </div>
        <div id="blankcol" class="w3-col" style="width: 5%">
&thinsp;</div>
        <div id="linkcontainer" class="w3-col" style="width: 75%">
            <div class="w3-col links" style="width: 20%">
                Link 1</div>
            <div class="w3-col links" style="width: 20%">
                Link 2</div>
            <div class="w3-col links" style="width: 20%">
                Link 3</div>
            <div class="w3-col links" style="width: 20%">
                Link 4</div>
            <div class="w3-col links" style="width: 20%">
                Link 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<video id="bgvid" autoplay="" controls="" 
   loop="" muted=""   poster="images/background.jpg">
<source src="http://testweb.creatink.org/video/1.MP4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div class="w3-container">
    <div id="restlist" class="w3-col" style="width: 20%">
        <button id="abarButton" class="restaurantButton" type="button">
        A Bar</button>
        <button id="artolyeButton" class="restaurantButton" type="button">
        A‎&reg;tölye</button>
        <button id="burgercityButton" class="restaurantButton"type="button">
        Burger City</button>
        <button id="cafedaysButton" class="restaurantButton"type="button">
        Cafe Days</button>

           ..... //Buttons continue

      </div>
    <div id="blankcol" class="w3-col" style="width: 5%">
&thinsp;</div>
    <div id="menu" class="w3-col" style="width: 75%">

       <div class="donatello">
            <p class="restName">Donatello Pizza</p>
            <table class="w3-table">

                <?php
/*PHP code for showing the menu of a restaurant
?>
                 ......................
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to post your code in your question. You saw the warning, yet you though it didn't apply to you so you highlighted links as code to get around it.

Comment: code of the whole page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You have a bunch of console errors too.

Post a Jsfiddle of your own on what you can't get working. Not the whole page...

Answer (score 0):

It's called a SPA (Single Page Application).

So here is a jfiddle that displays what your site currently does. Are you wanting help with the functionality as well?

All you do is add all the resources (js/css files etc) one at a time and then add your html (everything in the  tag).

You guys should use AngularJS to do this site. It's made for these sort of apps.

http://jsfiddle.net/jz3pLL22/

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
   var target = $(this).attr('rel');
   $("#"+target).show().siblings("div").hide();
});
```